# why is this minecraft command not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ gold_block -1 tp @A[x=-12.002,y=157,z=-48.982,r=2] ~ ~10 ~
```

This command works in a separate location using different coordinates, but when I use these coordinates, it fails to detect any players. This is the original command that I changed:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ iron_block -1 tp @a[x=12,y=153,z=-65,r=5] ~-5 ~-5 ~-5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have decimal coordinates in a selector, round them off to the nearest integer:

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ gold_block -1 tp @a[x=-12,y=157,z=-49,r=2] ~ ~10 ~
```